# How to get multiple counts on different conditions in same query in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get multiple counts in the same query but with different conditions.

- SELECT `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT (columnA) as TotalCounts`
- SELECT `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT (columnA) where sum(columnB + ColumnC) > 0 as Engaged`
- SELECT `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(columnA) where sum(columnB + ColumnC) = 0 as NonEngaged`

In theory, Engaged+NonEngaged will be equal to TotalCounts in my scenario

Comment: `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT` is a function for BigQuery Legacy SQL! Are you still bound to Legacy dialect or open for BigQuery Standard SQL?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant nope not bound to `Exact_Count_Distinct`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL *(make sure you preserve first row in below script which set Standard SQL to be used even if you don't explicitly set this in UI or whatever tool, library, api you use)*

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT columnA) AS TotalCounts,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(flag , columnA, NULL)) AS Engaged,
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(NOT flag , columnA, NULL)) AS NonEngaged
FROM (  
  SELECT columnA, SUM(columnB + ColumnC) > 0 AS flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY columnA
)
```

> Update to address extra question in comments - what if we need to get counts from two separate tables in the same query? let's say the 4th column in the same query above should get the distinct count of columnY from tableXYZ

The simplest option is to do as below. Cross Join is OK here because each result has just one row

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  TotalCounts,
  Engaged,
  NonEngaged,
  distinctY
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT columnA) AS TotalCounts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(flag , columnA, NULL)) AS Engaged,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(NOT flag , columnA, NULL)) AS NonEngaged 
  FROM (  
    SELECT columnA, SUM(columnB + ColumnC) > 0 AS flag
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    GROUP BY columnA
  )
)
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT columnY) distinctY
  FROM `project.dataset.tableXYZ`
)
```

Comment: sure, please consider voting up the answer :o)

Comment: just trying to learn, what if we need to get counts from two separate tables in the same query? So let's say the 4th column in the same query above should get the distinct count of columnY from tableXYZ.

Comment: it is really hard to answer new questions (or follow up questions that go beyond of scope of original question) within the comments - but if you will post new question i can easily answer there

Comment: I tried but it only let me post once in 90 minutes. I'll wait until that time Thanks again.

Comment: no problem i will add to my answer then - I think you should gain your reputation to be able to ask more frequently :o)  if my follow up answer does not cover your case or you have more questions  - please wait and post new ones! but meantime, just search here on SO - i have answered tons of similar questions. and if you found some and answers helped  - keep voting up them  - this will increase your reputation too

Comment: Amazing, this is great - works awesome. I went ahead and manage to extend this to include data from 5 different tables for a use case for us. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: sure, no problem. come back with new questions :o)